# How do I override a method to make it return the number 2 only? (Java)

Tags: java, overriding

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {
private int numOfSides;
private int[] sideValues = new int[getNumOfSides()];


public Dice(int numOfSides) {
    this.setNumOfSides(numOfSides);


    for(int i = 0; i < this.sideValues.length; i++) {
        sideValues[i] = i + 1;

    }
}
    public int Roll() {
        return (new Random()).nextInt(getNumOfSides()) + 1;


    }
    public int getNumOfSides() {
        return numOfSides;
    }
    public void setNumOfSides(int numOfSides) {
        this.numOfSides = numOfSides;
    }

}

import java.util.Random;

public class CheatDice extends Dice {



public CheatDice(int numOfSides) {
    super(numOfSides);

}

public int Roll() {
    return 2;


 }

}

 public class DiceTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dice a = new Dice(6);
    System.out.println(a.Roll());


    Dice b = new Dice(2120202);
    System.out.println(b.Roll());

    Dice d = new Dice(5);
    System.out.println(d.Roll());


  }

}
```

How do I override the Roll() method so that it prints the number 2 only? I am having trouble understanding overriding.

EDIT: Thanks for your answers. Could someone explain why you need a constructor with the same signature as the parent and child class constructors? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You already are overriding `Roll()` to return `2` in your cheating dice class.  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @azurefrog It's not printing the number 2 to the console when using these lines: Dice d = new Dice(5);
  System.out.println(d.Roll());

Comment: Your problem is that, while you have correctly defined `CheatDice` in which the `Roll` method from `Dice` is overridden, you have not created any instances of `CheatDice`.  BTW, in `CheatDice` you should add the `@Override` annotation in the declaration of `Roll()` so the compiler can warn you if your override is incorrect.   Also, the convention in Java is to use uppercase only for type names (Class, enumeration) and lowercase for methods.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you

Comment: Could someone explain why you need a constructor with the same signature as the parent and child class constructors? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: It is better to ask a separate question.

Comment: @JimGarrison No problem. I will do more research before I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the following change in your code when you call Roll :

```
Dice d = new CheatDice(5);
```

Now you would see 2 is being returned.